# Non-abelian Cartan subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, finite-fields

It is well-known that a Cartan subalgebra of a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 is abelian.

I guess this is not true in general. So, I would like to find a **finite field** $\mathbb{F}_q$ and a Lie algebra $L$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $L$ has a **non-abelian** Cartan subalgebra.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider finite-dimensional *semisimple* Lie algebras, as you do, 
there are such Lie algebras over $\Bbb{F}_q$, which have non-abelian Cartan subalgebras. More precisely, there are such Lie algebras of Cartan type $K_n$ and $H_n$ having $n+1$ and $2n+1$ conjugacy classes of Cartan subalgebras, respectively.

Reference: [Cartan subalgebras of simple nonclassical Lie p-algebras](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=2340&option_lang=eng).

Answer (score 0):

Take *any* nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak n$ (over *any* field) which is not abelian. Then $\mathfrak n$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak n$ which is not abelian.